# Method stops running after switching activities

Tags: android

In this app the users score is supposed to increase every second or so, and they can use that score and buy upgrades from the second Activity. When the user starts the app the program works fine, but when they go from the first activity to the second and back it stops updating the textview with the score that increases every second. Can you guys explain whats going on?

```
package com.example.navjeevenmann.mytycoon;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button myButton;
private int Counter;
private Button myButton2;
private TextView myTextView;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private int add = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        if (bundle.containsKey("Count")) {
            Counter = bundle.getInt("Count");
        }
        if (bundle.containsKey("Add")) {
            add = bundle.getInt("Add");
        }
    }


    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    myButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Counter = ButtonCounter(Counter);
        }
    });
    myButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Count", Counter);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Counter= AutoCounter(Counter, add);
            Display(Counter);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    },100);
}


public int ButtonCounter(int Counter) {
    Counter += 1;
    return Counter;
}

public int AutoCounter(int Counter, int add) {
    Counter += add;
    return Counter;
}

public void Display(int Counter) {
    String man = String.valueOf(Counter);
    myTextView.setText("$" + man);

}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You start the counting handler only inside `onCreate()` method.
When you go back from SecondActivity to MainActivity the `onResume()` method is called, So
You need to start the counting inside `onResume()` method.

**P.S** Make sure to check for nulls before updating you UI from `postDelay()`.

Your Activity might be destroyed by the time the code runs, make sure your TextView is not null before updating.